# Approval of Firefox extension with a flash banner

Tags: flash, firefox, xul, add-on

I'm developing an extension for Firefox. Can I get a full approval from https://addons.mozilla.org/, if I insert a flash banner located remotely into its XUL? For example, if I insert it using the iframe tag with type = "content"

Comment: You are probably better off asking this question on the [Mozilla Add-on Forum](https://forums.mozilla.org/viewforum.php?f=21) as that forum is specifically about Mozilla Add-ons. People who respond there will probably actually be add-on reviewers.

Comment: Actually #amo-editors IRC channel is the best for this go here: http://client01.chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org%3A%2B6697&channel=%23amo-editors